# Cannot read from python temp files

Tags: python, file-io

I have following code that I am having trouble with.

```
import os
import tempfile
import subprocess

def list_pids(pid):
  if pid == "" or pid == None:
    return False

  command = ["ps", "-U", "%s" % os.getuid(), "-o", "pid"]
  tmp = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False)
  process = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=tmp)
  tmp.seek(0) # hacky. but have to do it
  print tmp.tell()
  line = tmp.read()
  print tmp.tell()
  tmp.close()
  print tmp.name
```

This code is is meant to do a simple thing, get all PIDs for current user and dump the output in a named temp file.

Output of the program is:

```
0 # initial tell()
0 # tell() after read()
/tmp/tmp8DoUZj # name of named file
```

Can someone please figure out what is the issue here? The output is dumped in `/tmp/tmp8DoUZj` but I am not able to read it in python

Thanks for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call `assert process.wait() == 0` before you read the temp files.

Without that, your Python program is reading the temp file faster than `ps` populates it.

FYI Typically you don't need a temp file to read the stdout of the subprocess. Create it with `stdout=subprocess.PIPE`, and use e.g. `process.communicate()` to read its output.